# Error when trying to access uploaded files in Django application

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I have a Django application where I'm uploading some json files. When trying to access these files got 404 (not found) error.

The files are to load in a OpenLayers layer. If I use a json in project static files it works fine.

The files are uploading correctly to "uploaded_files" directory in project folder. But when trying to access these files in html page by object.file.url I always get error.

If I change MEDIA_URL to "/uploaded_files/" got error because it expects to find core/ or admin/ url.

Example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploaded_files/file.json

settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/core/uploaded_files/' # core is the application in django project. I have admin and core applications.
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploaded_files')
```

urls.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py file:

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.', '_'), filename)

class Estado(models.Model):
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.estado

class TipoFile(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tipo

class FileEstadoMunicipio(models.Model):
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(TipoFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    dat_criacao = models.TimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(), null=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, null=False)
```

html file:

```
{% load static %}

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                                  source: new ol.source.Vector({
                                    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:32722'}),
                                    url: '{{ alagamento.file.url }}'
                                    # url: '{% static "jsonfiles/cadastro_eixos_logradouros.json" %}' works fine
                                  }),

                                  style: style,
                                  opacity: 0.3
                                });
```

Error when in html page:

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/uploaded_files/1562551137_926604_SuscetibilidadeMovimentoDeMassa.json 404 (Not Found)

Please, advise if you find what I'm doing wrong.